# Multiple select on one derived table

Tags: mysql, sql

I've extracted a derived table, and I want to make different select request on the table, and then union them together.

The With As statement doesn't seem to work (I have sql 5.7.13) : a simple

```
WITH tag AS (SELECT * FROM vs_tag)
SELECT * FROM tag WHERE id < 20
```

gives me the error code 1064.

Also, I can't do

```
(select [queryA] from (select ...) as sub) union (select [queryB] from sub)
```

More specifically, I have a table with columns (category, value), and I want to extract the average for each category and the average for all categories.

Anyone has an idea how I should do that ? Thanks !

PS : I don't want to query the sub table twice as it is a long request

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? With [modern SQL](http://modern-sql.com/slides) you can use a common table expression.

Comment: I use MySQL. What's a common table expression ?

Comment: Read the "modern SQL" link or [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) - but CTEs are not available in MySQL

Comment: What about a scratch table? i.e. a permanent base table with the correct columns (design time) but gets cleared and repopulated as required (run time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how to return the average for each category and the average for all categories with one pass:

```
select category, avg(value) average
from mytable
group by category
with rollup
```

Adding `with rollup` adds an extra row (whose category will be `null`) that has the average across all categories.

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I was looking for. However, the `with rollup` doesn't seem to work with `order by`. Any ideas ?

Comment: @nic if it doesn't work, you can always wrap it: `select * from (<above query>) t1 order by 1`

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian your idea works. However, I just found out my problem is a little more complicated than that. Instead of two columns, I know have three (category, user, value), and I want to have the average for each pair (category, user) and the global average. Using what you said it seems that the with rollup gives me the average for every category. Thanks again for your time

Comment: Finally I just used a filter in the outer select where i filtered the entries with null values that I didn't want. Thanks very much !